# Is there a way to run lints/code style checks on a MR diffs and post results inline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, lint

Is there some integration available in GitLab for various linters/formatting tools?

Of course, you can always manually program a pipeline step that'd get the tested diffs, run the tool on them and fail if it encounters any issues, but that's suboptimal from usability perspective (especially for huge diffs/logs).

I.e. some review tools support posting the lint/codestyle check results inline (see https://github.com/traveloka/hubormaster as an example of what I'd ideally want to achieve).

Is anything like this possible in the current GitLab? Is there a tracking issue for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Danger](https://danger.systems/ruby/) for something like this. You'd need a job which does the linting / formatting, and then have a `Dangerfile` (with some Ruby, if you use that option), which formats the message to include the line number.

You can check the [reference](https://danger.systems/reference.html) for their GitLab integration and options available.

---

Short example:

*.gitlab-ci.yml:*

```
danger:
  stage: lint
  image: <docker image with Danger>
  script:
    - danger --version
    - danger --dangerfile=Dangerfile --verbose
  tags:
    - docker
```

*Dangerfile:*

```
warn("Please add something", file: "README.md", line: 1)
```